# How can I set up a taxonomy category as my page on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have this theme on my ecommerce website and its called Soma. He is great but sadly, the team doesn't support anymore.

The question I have is how can I set up a category as a page? Cause on this particularly theme, the sidebar menu doesn't show up on normal pages, just on shop pages and categories pages.

I need to create a page that shows only one type of product, that's ease with woocommerce code. But the problem is that on that page, it doesn't show the sidebar menu.

I will put some prints here, maybe it can help.

Print of the problem:

[image: print of the problem]

```
    <?php

/*
Default Template Page
*/

get_header();

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$soma_vc = preg_match("/\[vc_row.*?\]/i", get_the_content());

$soma_page_class = "container";

if ($soma_vc && function_exists('vc_map')) {
    $soma_page_class = "n-container";
}
?>
    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr($soma_page_class) ?>">
        <?php
            the_content();

            // WP Link Pages
            $args = array(
                'before' => '<div class="navigation">', 
                'after' => '</div>'
            );
            wp_link_pages($args);
        ?>
    </div>
    
<?php
endwhile; endif;

// Comments
comments_template();

get_footer();
```

And this is what I need to put there:

```
    <?php if($soma_shop_sidebar != '2' && is_active_sidebar('shop-sidebar')) : ?>
    <div class="soma-overlay" id="woo-sidebar_overlay"></div>
    <div class="woo-sidebar fixed-lateral left item-delay_off">
        <div class="hide-scrollbar">
            <div class="inner-hide_scrollbar">
                <div class="woo-sidebar_padding">
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-close_button"><?php echo esc_html__('Close', 'soma') ?></a>
                    <?php get_sidebar('shop'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello! Could you edit your post to include code examples, both from the page where the sidebar appears and from the one where it doesn't? In order for other StackOverflow users to provide constructive answers, we need to see the actual code you're working with.

Comment: Done! I put that and I think that's the way it could work.

Answer (score 0):

This is one is still tough to assist on without seeing the full source of Soma, which isn't open-source.

However, if you simply need to customize the template used to display a single category, and there isn't a `category.php` template in the theme yet, this is the procedure:

#### 1. Create a custom template for single categories

Referring to the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category), you'll want to create a custom template called `category.php`

If you want the layout for this page to be similar to another existing template, simply copy that template's code into `category.php` to begin.

#### 2. Copy relevant sidebar code into your new category.php template

Add the sidebar code you've posted into your new category.php template, wherever it belongs in the layout.

If you're not sure where to put it, or you'd like to include a sidebar template in the same way that the Shop and Categories pages do:

- look at code of those templates where the sidebar does currently appear
- find the place where they include the sidebar template
- do the same thing in your new `category.php` file